# *** HELP *** ADB command line - Update/download Google Play Store apps

Tags: android, adb

What I am trying to do is force all app to update before a certain app is launched so it has the latest version.

When using ADB logcat, I am able to determine the course of action which showed it to be using "I/Intent: act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat='market://details?id={packagename}'"

adb -s 127.0.0.1:5555 shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d'market://details?id={packagename}'

Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat='market://details?id={packagename}' flg=0x10000000 }

Comment: 1) Who's app are you trying to update (your own or a third-party)? 2) Have you seen: [Linking to Google Play](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/linking-to-google-play#android-app)

Comment: It is not my own, it is an app that is already on there.

Comment: And are you trying to update on emulator or on device? Via app or adb?

Comment: Update on an emulator and via adb

Comment: Now ADB logcat is saying "I/Finsky  ( 2777): [1] frz.a(11): Selecting account [{random numbers & letters}] for package {package}. overriding=[true]"

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but hopefully it may help someone.
To update Netflix apk from google play store(com.netflix.ninja):
`adb shell "am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d 'market://details?id=com.netflix.ninja'"`